# port mac application to ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, macos

Is it possible to port mac source code to ios (iphone and ipad) easily. The mac application is using both C and Objective C languages. What i asssume is to create xib files for mac nib files, and port the code for ios. Any suggestions???
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. How hard it is depends on how heavily your desktop app relies on a keyboard, mouse and a large screen. In general, porting an app from the desktop to a mobile device is far from trivial, for reasons that have nothing to do with the portability of APIs and project files.

Comment: Thank you so much... Your answer is very clear, esp., the statement " How hard it is depends on how heavily your desktop app relies on a keyboard, mouse and a large screen", Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you're correct about what you need to do. Since Objective C is a strict superset of C, your code should run fine, although you'll obviously need to change the API calls to iOS-oriented ones. The main task would likely be to recreate your interface and how it hooks into your code, but that shouldn't be too much of a problem for a well-designed MVC application. You may also need to give consideration to your application's lifecycle - compared to Mac applications, iOS apps tend to be used for much shorter periods, and can be quit with little or no notice, so they need to keep a lot more of their state in persistent storage (or be ready to save it quickly and automatically on exit), rather than relying on the user triggering an explicit save.

Without knowing more about your application, I can't give you any more than this general advice. I can only recommend that you give it a shot - the simulator is free.

Comment: thank you so much... That helped me a lot in taking my decision, Cheers